# Git: How are copies of a file with a shared history handled?

Tags: git, version-control, git-history

I backup my CSS userstyles to a git repo like so:

```
❯ fd                                                                                            
stylus-2021-05-18.json
stylus-2021-05-20.json
```

These backup files are obviously mostly the same, i.e., `stylus-2021-05-18.json` is the past history of `stylus-2021-05-20.json`. How is this handled by `git`?

Obviously, I could just rename the files to `stylus.json` and let `git` handle the version control completely, but I was wondering if `git` is smart enough that it could work with these files automatically.

Comment: This is the very point of version control. git makes a blob from hashing the file's content and stores it. When you'll modify the file later, it'll create a new blob to represent the new content. The old content will be referenced by the older commit. *Everything committed* is stored "forever".

Comment: Your approach is wrong. The file must be named `stylus.json`. Each change must be committed. If you need to track file "milestone" you should put a `git tag` on it.

Comment: If the two different files are not actually identical, there will be no connection between them in your Git repo. Both blobs will be stored independently.

Comment: Wow, I just did some tests, and my understanding was all wrong. I'll write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Commits are created as full file snapshots, always, but garbage collection creates commit packs, which efficiently stores similar blobs using diff compression, whether they're from the same file or not.

#### Intro

My understanding of Git storing "diffs" rather than full files was all wrong. After having done some readings and some experiments, I see that it doesn't matter if you modify a file or create a copy of a file, when you commit the change or the new file, Git creates a brand new blob, every time.

But, that's pretty inefficient, because you end up with a lot of different copies of the same text, with small diffs between blobs. That problem gets fixed when Git creates packs. I don't fully understand how Git searches for things to pack, but inside a pack, it will store some blobs as whole blobs, and some others as diffs from other blobs.

#### Experiment

```
# create a big file and commit it
seq 1 1000000 | shuf > bigfile
git add bigfile
git commit -m'bigfile'
```

At this point, `find .git -ls` shows me one big blob (3.5MB) storing this 6.9MB file.

```
# modify the big file and commit the change
echo change >> bigfile
git commit -m'modify bigfile' bigfile
```

At this point, `find .git -ls` shows me **two** big blobs, each about 3.5MB. Seems pretty inefficient to me, but read on...

```
# Add another big file, similar to the first one, and commit it
cp bigfile bigfile2
echo some trivial change >> bigfile2
git add bigfile2
git commit -m'bigfile2'
```

Things don't get better: `find .git -ls` shows me **three** big blobs, each about 3.5MB!

Now, at some point when you push, Git might pack your sandbox, but we can force that to happen right now: run `git gc`. That's not just garbage collection, as I incorrectly thought, it's also creating commit packs. After running `git gc`, `find .git -ls` now reports a single pack of about 3.2MB. So my three big blobs were identified as similar, better compressed, and stored efficiently. I think this is called "diff compression".

#### References

Online posts I just read to answer this question:

- [Commits and snapshots, not diffs, by Derrick Stolee](https://github.blog/2020-12-17-commits-are-snapshots-not-diffs/) (link found in @Joachim Sauer's answer)
- [Git Internals - How Git works, by Kaushik Rangadurai](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/git-internals-how-works-kaushik-rangadurai/)

Comment: The history of the copied files gets lost though, no?

Comment: Indeed, diff compression does not connect the files, it's only more efficient blob storage. As far as git is concerned, `bigfile` and `bigfile2` are not related, and your `stylus*.json` files aren't related either.

Comment: *I don't fully understand how Git searches for things to pack* ... Nobody does :-) There's a file in the Documentation/Technical directory describing the general idea, but the details are complicated. One useful note: doing packing *too often* is actually sub-optimal. Doing packing *not often enough* is also sub-optimal. There's a tradeoff curve, and the low-entropy point depends on the data in the repository, so there's no single right answer. Each `git push` or `git fetch` does its own separate packing for the duration of the push/fetch, though.

Answer (score 0):

Purely from a technical perspective is easy: if two files in a git history ever have exactly (byte-for-byte) the same content, then they will reference [the same blob object](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)<sup>*</sup> and the actual content will only be stored once. So if your current version of `fileA` is the same as `fileB` from 2 commits ago, then they will still only be stored once in `.git` sub directory. This works no matter if the files have different names, are in the same commit or another or on different paths: as long as the content is identical, the blob will be reused.

On the other hand: if that happens too often, then that's a sign that you're using version control in a way it's not really meant to be used: a given commit shouldn't contain any "historical data" or "archive": that's what other commits/tags/branches are for. The HEAD of any given branch should contain exactly (and only) the stuff that's currently relevant for that branch. But that part is not something that's technically required: it's just convention on how git is usually used.

<sup>* Note that this reuse even goes to directory levels,I.e. if two directories contain identical sub-directories and files, they'll reference the same tree object. This makes storing "very similar" commits very efficient: effectively only the differences will have to be stored in addition. Note that commits are still [snapshots and not diffs](https://github.blog/2020-12-17-commits-are-snapshots-not-diffs/).</sup>

Comment: The question is for when the content of a file `B` is not the same as file `A`, but is a future history of `A` instead. I.e.: `cp A B; echo new >> B; git add B; git commit -am .`